# Django Template - Получить значение переменной из URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть путь, заданный как:

```
r"^foo/(?P<id>\d+)/$"
```

в шаблоне нужно получить значение переменной `id`

т.е. находясь на странице */foo/2/*, нужно получить "2"

возможно ли это сделать, не передавая значение *id* в `context` функции `render` и не используя собственные шаблонные фильтры/тэги?

Comment: Хм, а для чего? после перехода этот ID будет частью страницы. Можно его получить из js и вставить в нужные вам теги, например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ request.resolver_match.kwargs.id }}
```